# blender bge have chosshairs in center of viewport

Tags: game-engine

I have a simple little game I'm setting up, and I'm wondering, how do I put little cross-hairs in the center of the screen?

Comment: The most direct method is generally done with a small objects placed in front of the camera and parented to it, so it will always stay in place. This can be a plane with a texture or modeled geometry

Comment: you could make an overlay scene with crosshairs, and then use a scene actuator to add that overlay scene.

Comment: @X-27 Could you post that as an answer?  I don't know how to do that.  I don't know much about scenes, though I am okay at modeling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the top navigation bar of Blender you can see a dropdown including the word "Scene". That's the scene you're currently in. Press the + sign to create a new one and call it "HUD" for example. In this scene you put a camera at the center looking towards the grid floor. Put the camera in orthographic view. Press <kbd>0</kbd> on the numpad to look through the camera and place a crosshair at the center as you like.

Now switch back to your default scene and add a logic brick with

- Sensor: always (activate "true level triggering" to run each tick)
- Controller: And
- Actuator: Scene

On the actuator/scene brick change the mode to "Add overlay Scene" and for "scene" select the scene that you have created for your hud.

Press <kbd>P</kbd> to start the game and you should see your crosshair.